# Factorial in Python [codio]

Tags: python, codio

the assignment is  'We provide you with a value N. Calculate N! and output only the final result.'
Can not figure this out for the life of me and I do not understand why my code will not run in the least.

```
 # Get N from the command line
      import sys
      N = int(sys.argv[1])

      def factorial(N):
      num = 1
      while N >= 1:
      num = num * N
      N = N - 1
      print(N)
```

Comment: You want to print/return `num` not `N`; that is assuming your indentation is correct.

Answer (score 0):

First, fix the formatting of your code.. It doesn't look right..

Your code is working fine. But you are printing the wrong number as answer. The factorial is stored in `num`. So try printing `num` instead of `N`

Comment: "Your formatting is wrong" and "Your code works fine" is somewhat contradictory.